# SOAP API request missing header, wrapper and body

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

Our client is having a problem setting up a SOAP API call to send an email via a Triggered Send.

His code is in ETClient.java, and it follows the example from this page (Axis2 .zip file):
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/connecting_to_the_api_using_java_and_axis2/

The output of his code is here:

```
  <xml-fragment xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <par:Options/>
     <par:Objects>
     <par:Client>
     <par:ID>1376574</par:ID>
    </par:Client>
    <par:TriggeredSendDefinition>
      <par:CustomerKey>CMC_API</par:CustomerKey>
    </par:TriggeredSendDefinition>
    <par:Subscribers>
      <par:EmailAddress>asunandan@cmcagile.com</par:EmailAddress>
      <par:Attributes>
        <par:Name>Subject</par:Name>
        <par:Value>Japanese</par:Value>
      </par:Attributes>
      <par:Attributes>
        <par:Name>HTML__BODY</par:Name>
        <par:Value>THIS IS A TEST</par:Value>
      </par:Attributes>
      <par:SubscriberKey>asunandan@cmcagile.com</par:SubscriberKey>
    </par:Subscribers>
  </par:Objects>
</xml-fragment>
```

This output is generated on line 105 of ETClient.java.  If you look at the SOAP request, the problem with it is that it's just a fragment.  It doesn't include the wrapper, or the body or header of a request.

We can't figure out why this is happening.

One of the questions he asked is if he needs to install Rampart or if just including the library files is sufficient.

Any help you could provide would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have they attempted to install rampart and tried again?